# How can i use a textbox entry in userform to set a range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-365

i need to create a duplicate sheet in excel. however i want to automate the name of the sheet to be the Set variable. for Example if the Sheets name is Cats then i want it if possible to be Set ws= wb.Worksheets("Cats"). if its possible i do not want to have to adjust this manually

this is the code i have to replace table and and sheet name.... but i need to replace the oldtbl name and oldsheet name in a formulas.

```
Sub Button1_Click() 
Sheet1.Copy before:=Sheet3 
Dim shName As String 
Dim Currentname As String 
Dim tblName As String 
Dim OldName As String 
Dim ws As Worksheet Currentname = ActiveSheet.Name 
shName = InputBox("What is the sheet name?") 
tblName = InputBox("What is the table name?")
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Currentname).Name = shName 
Sheets(shName).ListObjects(1).Name = tblName
```

this is the code i have to replace table and and sheet name.... but i need to replace the oldtbl name and oldsheet name in a formulas.

```
Dim wb as workbook
Dim ws as worksheets
set ws=wb.worksheets("OldSheet")

Range("Oldtbl[Colors]").formula=""
```

Comment: Sub Button1_Click()
Sheet1.Copy before:=Sheet3

Dim shName As String
Dim Currentname As String
Dim tblName As String
Dim OldName As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

Currentname = ActiveSheet.Name
shName = InputBox("What is the sheet name?")
tblName = InputBox("What is the table name?")
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Currentname).Name = shName

Sheets(shName).ListObjects(1).Name = tblName

End Sub

Comment: this will allow the sheet name to be changed and the table name to be changed the issue is now i am trying to figure out how to replace the old  table name with the one we changed the table to . Range("OldRange[1stcolumn]").formula so i need that old name changed to what the tblName is

Comment: that has been done